# Java: ClassCastException in certain situations

Tags: java, casting

I have following code:

```
static Object f(Object x) {
    x = (Integer) 1234; // <- it runs OK (why?)
    System.out.println(x);
    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> before = new HashMap<String, String>();
    before.put("a", "b");

    HashMap<String, String> after = (HashMap<String,String>) f(before); // <- it fails
    System.out.println(after);
}
```

And this is my output:

```
1234
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

Why does casting from HashMap to Intger run with no error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does casting from HashMap to Integer runs with no error?

You're not casting from a HashMap to Integer.  You're casting an [auto-boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) `int` to an `Integer`.

> ```
> x = (Integer) 1234;
> ```

`1234` is an `int` literal which is auto-boxed into an `Integer` when you try to use it as a reference type.

---

You then return that `Integer` and get a `ClassCastException` because it cannot be cast to a `HashMap`.

> ```
> return x;
> ```

returns 1234, and this is then cast here

> ```
> (HashMap<String,String>) f(before)
> ```

which fails.

---

Maybe there's a conceptual error here.

`Object x` defines a box that can hold a reference to any type of object.

`f(myHashMap)` starts a function call that fills the box `x` with a reference to a hash map.

`x = (Integer) 1234` throws out the contents of the box and replaces it with a reference to an `Integer`.  This is legal because the declaration `Object x` establishes that that box can contain a reference to any object (or none:`null`).

You then return `x` from `f` whose return type is `Object` and use it here

```
HashMap<String, String> after = (HashMap<String, String>) f(before)
```

which is taking the contents of a box that can contain anything, and making sure that it can fit in a box named `after` that can only contain `HashMap<?,?>`s.

That doesn't work, because the reference returned by `f(before)` does not fit in that box.  Hence the exception at runtime.

---

You can reduce your program to the below to understand what's going on.

```
Object x = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(1234);               // Unnecessary cast.
HashMap<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) x;  // Fails due to type-unsafe cast.
```

and if you eliminate the use of `Object`, you will probably get the problem explained to you by the compiler

```
Integer x = (Integer) Integer.valueOf(1234);
HashMap<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

`1. x = (Integer) 1234; // <- it runs OK (why?)`

Here autoboxing is done so `int` is converted to `Integer` object and then casted to `Object`.Since `Object` is super type of `Integer` it is okay.

`2.HashMap<String, String> after = (HashMap<String,String>) f(before); // <- it fails`

here `f()` method returns `Object` and you are trying to cast this to `Integer`.`Integer` is not super type of `Object`.So you are getting `ClassCastException`.

According to [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

x = (Integer) 1234;  //There happens autoboxing. Compiler converts primitive int to Integer.
It looks like f() always returns Objcet that is-a Integer. And than you try to cast it to HashMap. Compiler doesn't complain that you try to cast Object(reference type of f() return value) to HashMap. However object type is Integer and it fails in runtime.